# How do I change the GDM Login Window top icon?

Tags: 10.10, gdm, xubuntu

After installing xubuntu-desktop on Ubuntu 10.10, The GDM window icon changed to a blue mouse, How to I return GDM to the default Ubuntu theme/icon.

I have tried the following which effectively changes the theme but doesn't modify the top icon.

http://www.n00bsonubuntu.net/content/how-to-change-login-screen-ubuntu-1010-maverick-meerkat

Answer (score 5):

Install [Ubuntu tweak](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/) which allows you to change it very easily.

Answer (score 2):

the icon is located at /usr/share/icons/LoginIcons/apps/64/computer.svg

root can overwrite this icon with another svg item.

you could also place a second icon there and change the value of /apps/gdm/simple-greeter/logo-icon-name in the configuration-editor.

Comment: There should really be a less destructive and graphical way to do this.

Comment: there used to be a very extensive login-manager to change themes and icons. it was changed in lucid.

Comment: @komputes - there is, you change the gconf icon setting for gdm. Or use Ubuntu Tweak.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me (Ubuntu 10.04): Do a left click on your username  in the panel (usually in the upper right of the screen). In the menu do a left click again . This opens the window "About " where your logon icon (and more) can be customised.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Run login to a recovery console and run `gksu -u gdm gnome-appearance-properties` and change the icon theme.
You could also google gdm2setup (Sorry I do not have a link handy).

Comment: There is a side-effect that an accessiblity icon will be added the notification area gnome-panel applet of the user who ran the command. It is suggested instead that one logs out before running the above command.