# Rollback Xubuntu-desktop install: Change GDM Theme

Tags: apt, xubuntu, gdm

I recently installed xubuntu-desktop but much to my dismay, lots of applications came with it that I didn't want.

I apt-get removed xubuntu-desktop but it turns out I had to go through each programme and remove it manually anyway, now that I have done that, I have a proper desktop apart from the login screen still shows the Xubuntu theme.

How can I change it to its original Ubuntu default theme?

Is there a way that avoids installing Ubuntu Tweak?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems an age now, but you could use `gksudo gdmsetup` to customise your GDM login screen.  This seems to have been dropped after Karmic.

If you want to re-theme your GDM, add `gnome-appearance-properties` to GDM's `autostart` folder:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/applications/gnome-appearance-properties.desktop /usr/share/gdm/autostart/LoginWindow
```

Log out.

The appearance properties window will appear on the GDM login screen.

Configure GDM how you want, then close the window and log back in.

When you're done and want the window to stop opening with GDM, run:

```
sudo unlink /usr/share/gdm/autostart/LoginWindow/gnome-appearance-properties.desktop
```

Use this [AU question and answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10024/how-do-i-change-the-gdm-login-window-top-icon) to reset the xubuntu gdm icon back to the canonical orange circle-of-friends.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall the `gdm` package. This should reset everything like it was before the Xubuntu install.

Comment: This answer would be improved if you were to explain specifically *how* to do this.